# Ocultar un div al seleccion un boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, modal, function

Tengo un div con un select, un input y un botón
En mi función tengo que para mostrar el input y el botón tengo que seleccionar algo del select y ya me los muestra esto si lo hace correctamente

Pero estoy tratando de ocultar todo ese div, que cuando yo selecione un botón me despliega un modal y lo que quiero es que si el div se ve el input y boton me oculte todos eso y me muestre solo mi modal

Esta es la fución que me muestra el input y del texto y mi boton de buscar

```
mostrarBuscar = function ()
 {                                                                                          
      var select = $("#selectDiv").val();
      if (select === "alumno" || select === "maestro" || select === "director")
          {
                 $("#inputBuscar").attr("style", "display: show"); 
          } else {
                      $("#inputBuscar").attr("style", "display: none");
                  }
};
```

Y el del modal que quiero mostrar es

```
ocultarSelectBuscar = function()
 {
      var reasingar = $("#reasignarCard").val();
      var select = $("#busquedaSelect").val();

      if(reasingar === 0 && select !== "0")
        {
            $("#rowSelectBuscar").attr("style","display: show");
        } else {
                    $("#rowSelectBuscar").attr("style","display: none");
                 }
};
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, si pudieras ser mas claro te lo agradecería, además considera agregar tu HTML

Comment: probablemente reasignar sea el string "0" por lo que no se cumple que sea === 0. Qué pasa si lo casteas via `parseInt`? PD: debieras usar "display: block". No existe display: show

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi código de html es una lista desplegable que solo me muestra el select cuando selecciono por ejemplo alumno me muestra el div donde esta el input para ingresar texto y el boton de buscar

```
 <div class="container fist" >
            <div class="row" id="rowSelectBuscar">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="btn-group mr-2" style="margin-left: 10px">
                        <select  id="busquedaSelect" onchange="mostrarInputBuscar()">
                            <option value="0"> Seleccione una opción </option>
                            <option value="alumno "> alumno </option>
                            <option value="maestro"> maestro </option>
                            <option value="director"> director</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <div id="inputBuscar" style="display:none">
                        <input type="search" name="search" id="buscar">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="buscar()"> Buscar </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Mi duda es que cuando todo esto este visible ocultarlo por medio de otro boton que me mostrara una tabla sobrepuesta de todo el texto